# merging tcpdump from two different interfaces

Tags: linux, shell, tcpdump

Can you please help me to get an idea, how to do the following requirement?

I have two ethernet ports on a server. Eth0 and Eth1. Both interfaces are carrying traffic. I want to capture packet-dump both of the interfaces and merge into one file.

Thank you
Luke

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/805006/tcpdump-on-multiple-interfaces

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately questions like these are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow, and therefore should be asked here:
[ServerFault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

As the answers to [Tcpdump on multiple interfaces](https://serverfault.com/questions/805006/tcpdump-on-multiple-interfaces) provide, which @Marged linked to above, you can run [`tcpdump`](https://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) (or [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) or [`dumpcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/dumpcap.html)) specifying `-i any` as the interface if you don't mind capturing traffic on all interfaces.  And if you *only* want traffic on those 2 specific interfaces, then you can simultaneously run 2 separate instances of the capture tool, one capturing on the eth0 interface, the other capturing on the eth1 interface and then merge the two capture files together using a tool such as [`mergecap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/mergecap.html).

Alternatively - and much simpler in my opinion - is to just use a single instance of either `dumpcap` or `tshark` to capture traffic on both interfaces to a single capture file with no merging of separate capture files needed at all.  As the man pages for those tools indicate, *"This option can occur multiple times. When capturing from multiple interfaces, the capture file will be saved in pcapng format."*

For example:

```
tshark -i eth0 -i eth1 -w eth0_eth1.pcapng
```

Comment: Hi Chris, can I rotate the above command every 15sec and can we compress into tar.gz at the end of the 15 sec ? likewise, it will generate a number of files until thsark process been stopped.

Comment: As the `dumpcap` and `tshark` man pages indicate, you use the `-b duration:value` option (where *value* is the number of seconds) to specify how long to capture packets before switching to the next file.

Since neither `dumpcap` nor `tshark` support writing compressed capture files (yet), you will have to come up with an alternate solution to handle that yourself.  Peter Wu has already opened a bug report requesting support for writing compressed capture files by these tools, but thus far nobody has implemented it.  The bug is here: https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9311